# The limit of $\frac{|A_n|}{n^2}$

Tags: calculus, probability, sequences-and-series

Let $A_n=\{(i,j)\in\mathbb{Z}^2:\gcd(i,j)=1, \ \  0 \leq i,j\leq n \}$. How to prove the existence of $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|A_n|}{n^2}$, and how calculate this limit?

Thank you!

Comment: What information do you have? This is a well-known limit $\dfrac{6}{\pi^2} = \dfrac{1}{\zeta(2)}$. Essentially, the limit is $(1-1/2^2)(1-1/3^2)(1-1/5^2)\dots$, where the product runs through all primes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $n=1$, then $|A_n|=3$. From now on $n>1$. Denote 
$$
A_n^{<,j}=\{(i,j)\in A_n: i<j\}\\
A_n^{=}=\{(i,j)\in A_n: i=j\}\\
A_n^{>,i}=\{(i,j)\in A_n: i>j\}
$$
Then from definition of Euler's function it follows that $|A_n^{<,j}|=\varphi(j)$ and $|A_n^{>,i}|=\varphi(i)$. Obviously $|A_n^{=}|=1$, so
$$
|A_n|=|A_n^{=}|+\sum\limits_{j=1}^n|A_n^{<,j}|+\sum\limits_{i=1}^n|A_n^{>,i}|=1+2\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\varphi(k)
$$
Then the desired limit is equal to
$$
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{|A_n|}{n^2}=2\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\varphi(k)
$$
As [wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Growth_of_the_function),
$$
\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\varphi(k)=\frac{3n^2}{\pi^2}+\mathcal{O}\left(n(\log n)^{2/3}(\log\log n)^{4/3}\right)
$$
hence the answer is $6\pi^{-2}$

Comment: But, why the limit do exist?

Comment: How can I explain the existence of limit witout actually try and compute it?

Comment: I don't think there is a pedestrain solution here. Somehow you had to compute this limit