# On proving the convergence of $1/n^2\sum_{1\le k\le n}\varphi(k)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, summation, asymptotics, totient-function

Let $$\Phi_n=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n\varphi(k).$$ How one can show that  $\Phi_n$ is convergent sequence? 
(Here, $\varphi$ denotes the  Euler's  totient function.)
And please, without any monster asymptotic estimations.

Thank you!

**EDIT:**

Can we actually prove the convergence without finding the limit?

Comment: Where did you get this?

Comment: From here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/461108/the-limit-of-fraca-nn2

Comment: $$
\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\varphi(k)=\frac{3n^2}{\pi^2}+\mathcal{O}\left(n(\log n)^{2/3}(\log\log n)^{4/3}\right)
$$

Comment: Yes, also $\sum_{n\leq x}\phi(n)=\frac{3}{\pi^{2}}x^{2}+O\left(x\log x\right)$, but I can't prove these.

Comment: In that case, what is your precise background, and why are you investigating this area?

Answer (score 3):

$\sum_{k=1}^n\varphi(k)$ counts pairs of integers $a,b$ with $a < b \le n$. So if we ignore the $a < b$ condition the thing we are taking the limit of is just the probability that if we take two numbers $a, b$ less than $n$ at random that they are relatively prime.  For large enough $n$ we have the probability that two numbers is divisible by a prime $p$ is very close to $1/p^2$.  Now doing an inclusion-exclusion over primes we get: $P(a,b \ \text{have a common factor}) = \sum_{p}p^{-2} - \sum_{p_1,p_2}p_1^{-2}p_2^{-2} + \sum_{p_1,p_2,p_3}p_1^{-2}p_2^{-2}p_3^{-2}-...$. So $P(a,b \text{ are relatively prime}) = (1-2^{-2})(1-3^{-2})... = 1/\zeta(2) = 6/ \pi^2$. Halving this to take into account the $a<b$ condition gives the desired result.  Yea, I'm being a bit fuzzy on the convergence details but this is definitely the idea.

Comment: Perhaps you mean "...counts pairs of **coprime** integers ..."

Comment: +1, A question:
May I say that the existence of that limit deduced only from your question(stated in my own words): For two "random" integers $a$ and $b$, what is the probability that they have no common factor?

Comment: details in Hardy and Wright, theorems 330 and 332, pages 268, 269 in the fifth edition.

Answer (score 1):

We certainly have $\varphi(k)\le k \space\forall k\ge 1$, and $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^nk=\frac{1}{2}$. This shows that $\lim \sup \Phi_n\le 1/2$. It is known that $\Phi_n\sim \frac{3}{\pi^2}$.

Comment: It's not that simple. Let $$\psi(k) = \begin{cases} 0 &, 2^{2m}\leqslant k < 2^{2m+1}\\k &, 2^{2m+1}\leqslant k < 2^{2m+2}\end{cases}$$ The corresponding $\Psi_n = \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n \psi(k)$ doesn't converge.

Comment: this is not a series, this proves that $\lim sup \Phi _n \leq \frac{1}{2}$, but why $\lim inf \Phi _n = \lim sup \Phi _n$

Comment: Yes, you are right.